# Tkinter: configure multiple widgets simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to set the background of multiple widgets in a row at once. However, in the example you can see that sometimes the colorization is ugly: Widgets change color in separate times. How to update the appearance (configuration) of multiple widgets simultaneously? Virtual events would solve this issue?

```
import tkinter

class Application(tkinter.Tk):

  TITLE = 'Simultaneous Widget Blink Test'
  BLINK_INT = 75

  def __init__(self, rows=4, cols=10):
    super().__init__()
    self.rows, self.cols = rows, cols
    self.frames = [[] for _ in range(rows)]
    self.labels = [[] for _ in range(rows)]
    self.withdraw()  # assembling in background...
    self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    self.title(self.TITLE)
    self.build()
    for ri in range(self.rows):
      self.curr_ri = ri
      self.set_row_style()
    self.curr_ri, self.curr_n = 0, 0
    self.deiconify()  # showing it
    self.blink_again()

  def build(self):
    for ri in range(self.rows):
      for ci in range(self.cols):
        f = tkinter.Frame(self, width=40, height=40)
        self.frames[ri].append(f)
        f.grid(row=ri, column=ci, sticky='news')
        l = tkinter.Label(f, text='{}{}'.format(ri, ci))
        self.labels[ri].append(l)
        l.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='c')

  def blink_again(self):
    if self.curr_n == 10:
      self.curr_n = 0
      self.curr_ri += 1
    if self.curr_ri == self.rows:
      self.curr_ri = 0
    self.curr_n += 1
    self.highlight_row()

  def highlight_row(self):
    self.set_row_style(bg='orange')
    self.after(self.BLINK_INT, self.restore_row)

  def restore_row(self):
    self.set_row_style()
    self.after(self.BLINK_INT, self.blink_again)

  def set_row_style(self, bg='white'):
    for w in self.frames[self.curr_ri]:
      w.configure(bg=bg)
    for w in self.labels[self.curr_ri]:
      w.configure(bg=bg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = Application()
  app.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: More simplified example code.

Comment: is this your actual code? You don't need threads to accomplish a simple task like blinking some widgets, and threads and queues are almost certainly the source of your problem. You seem to already know how to use `after` to run a function periodically, why are you using threads?

Comment: This is an example code. I had to remotely control the real application. However, all they do is putting row indices to the queue. The `loop()` gets those row indices and does a single blink. `set_row_style()` is responsible to configure 2 * 10 widgets' background color in a single call. My problem is that those style changes does not appear at the simultanously which results ugly flickering. I don't see the queue would be responsible but I can try it without using queues.

Comment: Got rid of threading and queue. Problem still persist.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are updating the widgets is the proper way to modify multiple widgets at once. As long as you don't have any calls to `update` or `update_idletask` in the loop that modifies all of the widgets, the modifications should all appear simultaneously the next time there is a refresh on the screen (ie: when your function returns control to the event loop).

When I run your code I see no flickering. It all behaves as I expect.

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes it needs more cycles to perform flickering for some blinks. I always program on old PC, perhaps that is the reason you don't see it. If I put `time.sleep(1)` in `set_row_style()` the flickering appears even more in the first frames of the rows. Weird behavior. This is a simplified version of a display application of mine which has more complex widgets and the flickering is even more annoying there. Maybe I have to switch to another GUI then.

Comment: @SzieberthAdam: adding a sleep will definitely cause a flicker and/or other problems. So, you are saying this exact code you posted flickers when run?

Comment: Well, `time.sleep()` was a wrong way to demonstrate it then. I of course do not call `time.sleep()` in my GUI code normally. The current code in my post flickers on my PC, yes, but not every time. Usually in every 20-30 seconds.